# What is the right way to create separate npm modules and use them locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm

I created a React Native component which lives in a different folder with its own `package.json` file, and I want to use it in another project

`MyComponent` is located in `Workspace/MyComponent` and as a few dependencies in `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1"
  }
```

I am currently in the development of `MyComponent` so I have run `npm install` in the repo, there is a `node_modules` folder.

My have linked `MyComponent` with `MyApp` which is located in `Workspace/MyApp`, using `npm link`

Although, when I run `MyApp` and try to use `MyComponent`, it complains about duplicated declaration, because `react` is in both `MyComponent` and `MyApp`, and they are linked.

If I remove the `node_modules` folder from `MyComponent`, `react-navigation` complains about `react` not defined.

In the ReactJS world, webpack for example allow to set the root with the preferred node_modules folder which is great.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
  }
  ...
}
```

I wish to do something similar so I don't have duplicated modules and can debug `MyComponent` in `MyApp` locally without reinstalling `MyComponent` for every single change. What is the best approach for me to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that will eventually be put in its own repo and then will be installed like any other component, I would probably just build it in the node_modules directory of the parent project.  That would prevent you from having to run `npm install` for every little change.

You can also declare a dependency on a local file and then npm will install it in node_modules

```
  "dependencies": {
    "my-component": "file:app/components/my-component",
  }
```

So I have a component that I've built within my project that is referenced in my package.json file.  When I run `npm install` this component is installed in the node_modules folder.  That could help with the duplicate library declarations but it wouldn't solve the repeated use of `npm install`

Update: I just learned that npm 5 doesn't copy the files over to the node_modules folder. It now creates a symlink (basically, a virtual directory that points to the real one) to the code in your project.

This means you will not have to run `npm install` each time you change your code so it will likely be the best solution for you.

Comment: [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) is another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question, and it's called `whackage`
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/whackage